# Under which condition a star-shaped function is convex?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

In the following let us consider, without essential loss functions such that $f(0)=0$.
A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is called *star shaped* if its epigraph is star shaped with respect to $(0,0)$, or in other words:
$$\forall\alpha\in [0,1]\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\quad f(\alpha x)\leq \alpha f(x)$$
I am searching for a condition which, added to star-shapedness ensures (or even better is equivalent to) convexity of $f$.
I know that a set is convex if and only if it is star shaped with respect to any of its points. Hence a way may be building on this fact, workning on the epigraph of $f$. But I don't really know if this would give a useful sufficient condition on $f$.
Any help would be most welcomed.

Comment: @lulu Is $(x^2-1)^2$ star shaped with respect to $(0,1)$? I don't see how you can connect $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$  with a segment which lies in the epigraph of it. Anyway, let me edit the question, it will be clearer.

Comment: No, it isn't (and I deleted my inaccurate comment accordingly).  It seems hard to construct an example which isn't convex...do you have one in mind?  Nice question by the way (+1).

Comment: Thanks! I think it's not easy to find an analytical example, here is a graphical https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Amaury-Van-Bemten/publication/325442731/figure/fig3/AS:631920224387072@1527672930662/Example-of-concave-convex-and-star-shaped-functions.png one